# How to set a frame for DataScannerViewController in Swift? The default scans the whole camera and I need to specify the frame to limit the input

Tags: swiftui

I need to limit the camera scanner to read an input of 16-digits PIN only, something similar to this (from a different app):
[image]

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. `recognizedDataTypes: [.text(textContentType: .telephoneNumber)]` -> Doesn't show a frame, but it forces the focus to look for max 14-digits only (I need 16)
2. Add regionOfInterest to the view controller, but it's not changing anything:

   let viewController = DataScannerViewController(...)

   viewController.regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)

   viewController.delegate = context.coordinator

   return viewController
3. Tried adding frame:

   let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 200, height: 300)
   viewController.view.frame = frame

But that didn't change anything either

Here's the full code:

```
struct CameraScannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Binding var startScanning: Bool
@Binding var scanResult: String

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> DataScannerViewController {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
    let viewController = DataScannerViewController(
        recognizedDataTypes: [.text(textContentType: .telephoneNumber)],
        qualityLevel: .fast,
        recognizesMultipleItems: false,
        isHighFrameRateTrackingEnabled: false,
        isHighlightingEnabled: true)
    //viewController.view.frame = frame
    //viewController.regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
    viewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    return viewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: DataScannerViewController, context: Context) {
    if startScanning{
        try? viewController.startScanning()
    }else {
        viewController.stopScanning()
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, DataScannerViewControllerDelegate {
    var parent: CameraScannerViewController
    init(_ parent: CameraScannerViewController){
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didTapOn item: RecognizedItem) {
        switch item {
        case .text(let text):
            parent.scanResult = text.transcript
            dataScanner.stopScanning()
            dataScanner.dismiss(animated: true)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For 1. you could let the scanner recognize text in general and then filter it yourself for your specific needs.

For 2. and 3. you can add an PartialTransparentView with a cutout.

```
class PartialTransparentView: UIView {
var cutout: CGRect?

init(cutout: CGRect?) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.cutout = cutout
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
    isOpaque = false
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    backgroundColor?.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    guard let cutout = cutout else { return}
    
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: cutout)
    let intersection = rect.intersection(cutout)
    UIRectFill(intersection)
    
    UIColor.clear.setFill()
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setBlendMode(.copy)
    path.fill()
}
```

}

Then you calculate the boundries for the rect (I made it dynamic in the example) and add this view to the `datascanners.view`.

```
let width: CGFloat = view.bounds.width - 32
let height: CGFloat = 64
let viewXPosition: CGFloat = 16
let viewYPosition: CGFloat = (bounds.height / 2) - (height / 2)
let cutout = CGRect(x: viewXPosition, y: viewYPosition, width: width, height: height)
let partialTransparentView = PartialTransparentView(cutout: CGRect(x: viewXPosition, y: viewYPosition, width: width, height: height))

datascanner?.view.addSubview(partialTransparentView)
partialTransparentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
partialTransparentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
partialTransparentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
partialTransparentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
partialTransparentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

I tested this only in my own context. Let me know if you have any further questions.